# Be able to change database connection in runtime with Laravel

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel

So I am making a web application which should be able to upload any SQL statement to any server listed in the database on a schedule. It should connect to the database, execute the statement and make a report based on the information received. Then it can disconnect.

Currently, I have a job in place and it grabs all the information required from the database eg. host, port, DBName etc. I just need to form a connection and then execute the statement.

I am using the Laravel framework.

Edit: I cant modify any database configs as the database information is stored in a table, not a config file.

Thanks

Comment: Is the config table modelled/a php class? If that's the case, you can probably set up something that will let you set that class as active. Maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it at runtime this way:

```
$connKey = 'CustomConnection';

$dbInfo = DatabaseInfo::find($databaseId);

Config::set('database.connections.' . $connKey, array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => $dbInfo->hostName,
    'database'  => $dbInfo->database,
    'username'  => $dbInfo->username,
    'password'  => $dbInfo->password,
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
));

// Now you can set the new connection to the models

$myModel = new MyModel;
$myModel->setConnection($connKey);

// Or you can use it this way too:
$users = DB::connection($connKey)->select(...);

// Or, also:
$pdo = DB::connection($connKey)->getPdo();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in a very similar way to one posted :

```
    $connectionName = Crypt::encryptString(str_random(80));


    DB::purge("$connectionName");


    Config::set("database.connections.$connectionName", [
        "driver" => "$Driver",
        "port" => "$Port",
        "host" => "$Host",
        "database" => "$DBName",
        "username" => "$UserName",
        "password" => "$Password"
    ]);        


    $query = DB::connection("$connectionName")->select($statement);

    $query= json_decode( json_encode($query), true);


    Excel::create("$filename-$mytime", function($excel) use ($query, $filename) {

            $excel->sheet("$filename", function($sheet) use ($query){

                $sheet->fromArray($query);

            });

        })->store('xls', storage_path('excel/exports'));
```

This creates a new connection with a random name (so when in a queue if multiple are executed they wont purge the same database), assigns the details to it, executes the select statement which is defined in the variable $statement. Then creates an excel spreadsheet from that.